# Получить записи за последний месяц

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Нужно получить id клиента, количество и сумму заказов за последний месяц.

```
Paper::select('client_id', DB::raw('SUM(price) as `sum`'),DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `orders_per_month`'))
        ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
        ->groupBy('client_id')->get()
```

Пытался так, но если за последний месяц у клиента нет заказов, то он не выводится.

Comment: конечно он не будет выводиться, потому что условие `where` отсеит этих клиентов.

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, лучше ли это перенести в комментарий, или нет, т.к. это не полноценный ответ на вопрос, но если вам нужно вывести клиентов, даже если у них не было заказа, то вам нужен примерно такой запрос:

```
select distinct t1.client_id,
       IFNULL(sum_price, 0) as sum,
       IFNULL(count_price, 0) as count
from test t1 left join (select client_id,
                               sum(price) as sum_price,
                               count(*) as count_price
                        from test
                        where created_at >= STR_TO_DATE('01.09.2016', '%d.%m.%Y')
                        group by client_id) t2
     on t1.client_id = t2.client_id
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8ee0/7/0)